# Vue/Vuex - Module two depends on module one, and module one gets data from server

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuex

Check this out:

```
import accountModule from '@/store/modules/account/account';
import otherModule from '@/store/modules/other/other';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    account: accountModule,
    other: otherModule,
  }
});
```

The data initialization in `other` depends on the `account` module because the `account` module has user specific settings. Suppose `other.state.list` depends on `account.state.settings.listOrder`. However, I want the data for the `account` module to come from the *server*. Which is async. So when `other` is trying to get set up, it can't just try to reference `account.state.settings.listOrder` because the response from the server may not have come back yet.

I tried exporting a *promise* in `accountModule` that resolves with the module itself. But that approach doesn't seem to work.

```
import accountModulePromise from '@/store/modules/account/account';

accountModulePromise.then(function (accountMoudle) {
  import otherModule from '@/store/modules/other/other';

  ...
});
```

This gives me an error saying that `import` statements need to be top level.

The following doesn't work either:

```
let accountModule = await import '@/store/modules/account/account';
import otherModule from '@/store/modules/other/other';
...
```

It gives me an error saying that `await` is a reserved word. I'm confused though, because https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import says that I should be able to do it.

Comment: Still, why would want to delay the import of the *vuex module*. Or do you want to make an action inside `otherModule` wait on `accountModule`?

Comment: @Frank Ultimately, I want the setting of data in `otherModule` to wait for `accountModule`. But in order to do that, I'm thinking that I need to delay the import of `accountModule`, because I want that second line of code to only execute when the first line finishes getting its stuff from the server and getting set up.

Comment: Seems if other depends on account, then otherModule should import accountModule. Trying to resolve in the store seems wrong. What exactly is the dependency?

Comment: @eric99 In the sense of `other` being a submodule of `account`? If so, that's not the way I want things structured. If not, there's still the question of where I attach `account` to my Vuex store. If I start importing it in multiple places, it'll slow things down with lots of unnecessary network requests. And there's the further complication that (I ignored in this question to keep things simple) in my real app, there's many modules that depend on `account`.

Comment: If you're using the standard Vue CLI setup, imports are not a runtime instruction - rather webpack uses then to bundle the code. So, await can't be used with it and you cannot assign it's result (it's not a function call), and multiple references will not 'slow things down'. You should think of import as a compile-time declaration rather than a runtime instruction.

Comment: The other thing is Vuex stores are best thought of as piplines. Initially, the pipe is empty then when async data arrives, it runs through the pipes as you have constructed them. It would be easier to illustrate if you included an example of the dependency in the question. BTW, you can reference the store itself in a store module (rather than importing one module into another).

Comment: @eric99 Don't forget [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) :)

Comment: @AdamZerner You're thinking wrong. Initialize the store and (a)wait for `acountModule` to populate.

Comment: @eric99 Gotcha, that makes sense about how `import` works, I didn't realize that. Thinking about it some more, the approach of importing `account` inside of `other` seems like it'll work. But I'd have to export a promise from `account`, and thus export a promise from `other` as well. In reality I have more than one module that depends on `account`, so it would make things a little complicated with all the promises when I really just want line 2 to wait for line 1 in my first code block.

Comment: @eric99 As for an example of the dependency, suppose `account` has `account.settings.order` that can be `'ascending'` or `'descending'`, and `other` has `other.list`, that needs to be ordered based on `account.settings.order`. I'll update the question with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your last code block didn't work because of `await` have to be inside `async` function.

> Remember, the await keyword is only valid inside async functions. If
>   you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a
>   SyntaxError.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description).

You can use [Dynamic Module Registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration):

```
accountModulePromise.then(async () => {
  let otherModule = await import('@/store/modules/other/other');
  store.registerModule('other', otherModule.default);
});
```

But when you want to get state or dispatch actions you have to check whether module is registered which is pretty bad.

In my opinion it would be better if you redesign your module structure to decoupling each other. Try to move your initialize code to `main.js` or `App.vue` then dispatch actions to update module states from that.

---

**Updates**

From your last update, Another idea to decoupling your store, I think you should store your `list` without order and sort it only when you use. You can do this with:

Computed property:

```js
...
computed: {
  list () {
    let list = this.$store.state.other.list
    let order = this.$store.state.account.settings.listOrder
    if (!list || !order) return []
    return someSort(list, order)
  }
},

beforeCreate () {
  this.$store.dispatch('other/fetchList')
  this.$store.dispatch('account/fetchListOrder')
}
...
```

Or Vuex getters:

```js
...
getters: {
  list: (state) => (order) => {
    return someSort(state.list, order)
  }
}
...
```

```js
...
computed: {
  list () {
    let order = this.$store.state.account.settings.listOrder
    return this.$store.getters['others/list'](order)
  }
}
...
```

Comment: I would love to initialize the code in `main.js` or `App.vue`, but I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to do that. In `App.vue`, the timing is off, `App.vue` runs after my Vuex is set up. `main.js` I'm not sure how that would work. I want the account stuff to be in my store. I thought about just keeping my account stuff attached to `window` and referencing that from the store where it is needed, but that is ugly.

Comment: *"But when you want to get state or dispatch actions you have to check whether module is registered which is pretty bad."* What I was thinking is to just hide everything until the stores are all initialized. Not too bad IMO.

Comment: @AdamZerner I update my answer based on your last update. Not sure that you have other concerns.

Comment: The `await import(...)` approach works in a sense, but it leads to other problems. In `store/index.js` I want to export the store, but if I'm registering modules inside of `accountModulePromise`, it works out where other stuff is trying to use the store before it is set. I also tried putting everything inside an async IIFE, and it had the same problem.

Comment: As for the idea to decouple the store, I appreciate it and it may turn out to be the best approach for my real world use case, but I'm still interesting in the more general question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have two modules.  One with state that is fetched from the server, the other with state that is dependent on the first, correct?

I would suggest the following approach:

Set up your modules with empty 'state' to begin with.  Then create an action within accountModule to set up the state from the server.  Use a getter on `other` to order the list.  Finally, dispatch your action upon app creation.

```
const account = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        listOrder: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        setListOrder (state, newListOrder) {
            state.listOrder = newListOrder
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchServerState (ctx) {
            let result = await fetch("/path/to/server")
            ctx.commit('setListOrder', result.listOrder) 
            // or whatever your response is, this is an example
        }
    }
}

const other = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        unorderedList: []
    },
    getters: {
        list (state, getters, rootState) {
            return someSort(state.unorderedList, rootState.account.listOrder);
        }
    }
}
```

within App.vue (or wherever)

```
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('account/fetchServerState')
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to do the initialization in the store module files for a couple of reasons, but your approach isn't bad.